# Appium: Cannot select button within datepicker in android

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

I am doing a testing using appium on an android mobile app. My android version is 5.1.

The date-picker has a SET button used for confirming the date setting with a xpath:- `//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']/android.widget.Button[@index='6'].`

I always get `NoSuchElementException` at the end of the testing.

Can anyone explain what would be the possible causes except wrong xpath?

Here is the code:

```
     WebElement yearPicker = driver.findElementByXPath(yearView);
     yearPicker.click();
     // ... I omit the touch actions here
     WebElement set = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@index='6']");
     set.click();
```

Here is the appearance of the datepicker and the xml structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add Screen shot of the screen and also the code snippet?

Comment: I have posted an answer, hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the date picker UI differs from device to device. **Its better to hit enter key after you select the date**. I recommend using the first method if its work for you. Even if the UI changes, it will work if you hit **ENTER key** instead of Set/Done/OK etc

You can do it in two ways:

1. By pressing the enter key

   ```
   driver.longPressKeyCode(66);
   ```

**OR**

2. By finding the element:

   ```
     Thread.sleep(2000);
   ```

   `WebElement setButton=driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Set']");
   setButton.click();`

Comment: I think the pressKeyCode and longPressKeyCode functions is deprecated in my version. Currently, I am using java client 5.0.0 beta3

Answer (score 1):

May be the location of element is done before it appears, i suggest that you use

`Thread.sleep(5000);`

before starting the action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this://android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,"button1") and contains(@text,"Set")]

Secondly date picker differs for every device.
Thirdly give index the last priority.

Answer (score 1):

you can use resource id 'button1' e.g. driver.findElementById("button1")